# How to Call the ASPX file from a aspx engine view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you programmatically select items in a multi-select listbox using jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use the below  Code Snipped .
Just replace your conrtrol Id
JQuery Code:

```
var realvalues = [];

var textvalues = [];

$('#multiplelistbox :selected').each(function(i, selected)
 {
    realvalues[i] = $(selected).val();
    textvalues[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```